# Rijndael encryption between iOS and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ios, cryptography, rijndael

I am using the StringEncryption.m library in iOS to encrypt messages, and then decode them on a .Net project.

For 99.9% of messages, the encryption / decryption process works. However, there is a particular message that the iOS app sends which always results in a "Padding is invalid" error on the .Net project.

The problem message is 800 bytes long. If i force it to be 799 or 801 bytes, the encryption / decryption works.

Both sides are using CBC and the iOS solution uses PKCS7 padding.
Any ideas?

Comment: What padding are you using in .Net?

Comment: What is the offending message?

Comment: The .Net padding is the default (PKCS7)

Comment: I cant post the offending message as it contains private business information. It is an xml message.

Comment: @JonathanSmith - Come up with a different message.  You should also post the C# code that decrypts the message.  If you cannot provide us the information we need to answer your question you will be limited to the people at your disposal.

Comment: Just wanted to thank everyone for the comments. I managed to fudge through a random message and found that the problem occurs when the message length is a multiple of 16. Did a quick search and turned this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884119/encrypting-16-bytes-of-utf8-with-seckeywrapper-breaks-ccstatus-4304. Problem now solved. Again, many thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed Ramhounds guidance and produced a different message of the same length. Problem is down to the encryption library on the iOS.

Found the answer here: [Encrypting 16 bytes of UTF8 with SecKeyWrapper breaks (ccStatus == -4304)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884119/encrypting-16-bytes-of-utf8-with-seckeywrapper-breaks-ccstatus-4304)