# Convert RSA Public key (2048 bit) from XML format to DER ASN.1 public key for iOS

Tags: ios, rsa, keychain, asn.1, der

Am trying to create SecKeyRef from PublicKey (2048 bits) data shared by C# in XML format. The data looks like this:

`<Modulus>yLgpOFtg14GjDdle0xha2JCbYrpmKCpXcv+zFx2pi6OlIF8cOSXF6dE19W15+WfuCc2SznVQlVDOLp/NlPGLXKN5L47XYQrPpcls8/xp2PYYW7hjezx7Ig6+WDJnUxSbWgxZQMaiyO1XbCKll5yT2AxUj4od/DfylsVe8ljq154rEb+vCjr/LDpxExijHouJYDNqFV1jglWHWfftBQAzEZADPx7NpHsgXSYrFeVY/WH38GIlyO8FvGWIuDiwyRrHUEXhljmBqAJ3lgULyik3ShfjpN1W4h7BbzFs27mpiAPMtPgToADPNzOadRWFJQjeVVknIq5g6SHHnaZK8wBwrQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>]]>"`

I have followed the [Convert XML Dsig format to DER ASN.1 public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397065/convert-xml-dsig-format-to-der-asn-1-public-key) link, which works only for 1024 bits key but the same logic is failing to DER encode the above key (2048 bits). Though I could see in the comments that the conversion logic needs to be modified for 256 bytes key, am not able to succeed with alterations!

I have also tried [Generate Public Key From Modulus & Exponent on iOS using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844540/generate-public-key-from-modulus-exponent-on-ios-using-openssl) library, but failed to generate RSA object with this! Below is the sample:

`NSString *mod = @"yLgpOFtg14GjDdle0xha2JCbYrpmKCpXcv+zFx2pi6OlIF8cOSXF6dE19W15+WfuCc2SznVQlVDOLp/NlPGLXKN5L47XYQrPpcls8/xp2PYYW7hjezx7Ig6+WDJnUxSbWgxZQMaiyO1XbCKll5yT2AxUj4od/DfylsVe8ljq154rEb+vCjr/LDpxExijHouJYDNqFV1jglWHWfftBQAzEZADPx7NpHsgXSYrFeVY/WH38GIlyO8FvGWIuDiwyRrHUEXhljmBqAJ3lgULyik3ShfjpN1W4h7BbzFs27mpiAPMtPgToADPNzOadRWFJQjeVVknIq5g6SHHnaZK8wBwrQ==";`

```
BIGNUM *modulus = BN_new();
int res = BN_hex2bn(&modulus,[mod cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

BIGNUM *exponent = BN_new();
NSString *exp = @"AQAB";
res = BN_hex2bn(&exponent,[exp cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

RSA *rsa = RSA_new();

rsa->n = BN_new();
BN_copy(rsa->n,modulus);
rsa->e = BN_new();
BN_copy(rsa->e,exponent);
rsa->iqmp=NULL;
rsa->d=NULL;
rsa->p=NULL;
rsa->q=NULL;

FILE *fp = fopen("/publicKey.pem", "wb");
int suc = PEM_write_RSAPublicKey(fp, rsa, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
```

The generated publicKey.pem file is apparently empty!
It would be great if anyone can help me to import XML RSA public key into iOS SecKetRef object.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could successfully resolve this issue with both the approaches mentioned above. Here is my solution:

Approach # 1.Convert XML keys to ASN.1 DER format worked with 256 bytes key (2048 bits) with this link.
https://github.com/meinside/iphonelib/blob/master/security/CryptoUtil.m#L67

Approach # 2. Could successfully encrypt with the RSA object (reference: [Generate Public Key From Modulus & Exponent on iOS using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844540/generate-public-key-from-modulus-exponent-on-ios-using-openssl)) created with following code:

`NSString *mod = @"yLgpOFtg14GjDdle0xha2JCbYrpmKCpXcv+zFx2pi6OlIF8cOSXF6dE19W15+WfuCc2SznVQlVDOLp/NlPGLXKN5L47XYQrPpcls8/xp2PYYW7hjezx7Ig6+WDJnUxSbWgxZQMaiyO1XbCKll5yT2AxUj4od/DfylsVe8ljq154rEb+vCjr/LDpxExijHouJYDNqFV1jglWHWfftBQAzEZADPx7NpHsgXSYrFeVY/WH38GIlyO8FvGWIuDiwyRrHUEXhljmBqAJ3lgULyik3ShfjpN1W4h7BbzFs27mpiAPMtPgToADPNzOadRWFJQjeVVknIq5g6SHHnaZK8wBwrQ==";

NSString *exp = @"AQAB";

```
NSData *modBits = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:mod options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
NSData *expBits = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:exp options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

unsigned char *modBin = (unsigned char *)malloc(modBits.length);
[modBits getBytes:modBin length:modBits.length];

unsigned char *expBin = (unsigned char *)malloc(expBits.length);
[expBits getBytes:expBin length:expBits.length];


BIGNUM *returnValue = BN_new();
BIGNUM *modulus = BN_bin2bn(modBin, modBits.length, returnValue);
BIGNUM *exponent = BN_bin2bn(expBin, expBits.length, NULL);

RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
rsa->n = BN_new();
BN_copy(rsa->n,modulus);
rsa->e = BN_new();
BN_copy(rsa->e,exponent);
rsa->iqmp=NULL;
rsa->d=NULL;
rsa->p=NULL;
rsa->q=NULL;


unsigned char *orgTxt = (unsigned char*)strdup("Hello World");

int lenrsa = RSA_size( rsa ) - 11; // man RSA_public_encrypt for the -11

unsigned char *encrText = (unsigned char *)malloc(lenrsa);
int result = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen((const char*)orgTxt), orgTxt, encrText, rsa,RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

`Be sure of the glen param of RSA_public_encrypt API, it depends on the padding used.`man RSA_public_encrypt` for more details.